# Bank transfer synchronization

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock

i got that question on todays interview.

```
class BankAccount {
    private int money;

    public synchronized void deposite(int sum) {
        money += sum;
    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(int sum) {
        money -= sum;
    }

    public synchronized int getMoney() {
        return money;
    }
}

class accountManager {
    public void transfer(BankAccount a, BankAccount b, int money) {      
    }
}
```

So i need to write transfer() method, so it will be threadsafe and account balance should be >= 0.

```
public void transfer(BankAccount a, BankAccount b, int money) {
    synchronized ( a ) {
        synchronized ( b ) {
            int temp = a.getMoney() - money;
            if (temp >= 0) {
                a.withdraw(temp);
                b.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this, but it produces deadlock when we transfer from a to b and from b to a simultaneously. So the 2nd question is, how to fix deadlock?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid Deadlock example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326861/avoid-deadlock-example)

Answer (score 6):

You have to lock the objects in the same order or you will get a deadlock.

BTW: given the lock is much more expensive than the operation performed you are better off using a global lock or just one thread.