# Example of deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have checked many websites and the only example of `deadlock` is something like this. There is always a `synchronized` block inside a `synchronized` block.

(method `withdraw` is locked by `a` and method `deposit` is locked by `b`.)

```
class Account
{
    int balance;
    Account(int amount)
    {balance = amount;}

    void withdraw(int amount)
    {balance-=amount;}

    void deposit(int amount)
    {balance+=amount;}
}

class Threaddemo extends Thread
{
    Account a,b;
    int amount;

    Threaddemo(Account a,Account b,int amount)
    {
        this.a=a;this.b=b;this.amount=amount;
        start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        transfer(a,b,amount);
    }

    public void transfer(Account a,Account b,int amount)
    {
        synchronized(a)
        {
            a.withdraw(amount);
            System.out.print(amount+" is withdrawn from account a\n");

            try{Thread.sleep(500);}
            catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

            synchronized(b)
            {
                b.deposit(amount);
                System.out.print(amount+" is deposited into account b\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
class U3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Account a = new Account(1000);
        Account b = new Account(2000);

        new Threaddemo(a,b,100);
        new Threaddemo(b,a,200);

    }
}
```

but if we use a synchronized block after a synchronized block there will be no deadlock.

```
class Account
{
    int balance;
    Account(int amount)
    {balance = amount;}

    void withdraw(int amount)
    {balance-=amount;}

    void deposit(int amount)
    {balance+=amount;}
}

class Threaddemo extends Thread
{
    Account a,b;
    int amount;

    Threaddemo(Account a,Account b,int amount)
    {
        this.a=a;this.b=b;this.amount=amount;
        start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        transfer(a,b,amount);
    }

    public void transfer(Account a,Account b,int amount)
    {
        synchronized(a)
        {
            a.withdraw(amount);
            System.out.print(amount+" is withdrawn from account a\n");

            try{Thread.sleep(500);}
            catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        }
        synchronized(b)
        {
            b.deposit(amount);
            System.out.print(amount+" is deposited into account b\n");
        }
    }
}
class U3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Account a = new Account(1000);
        Account b = new Account(2000);

        new Threaddemo(a,b,100);
        new Threaddemo(b,a,200);

    }
}
```

If this is the only way to get deadlock then why don't we use two separate synchronized block?
If there are other ways to get deadlock please give example.

Comment: "why don't we use two separate deadlock"? how you want to use a deadlock??

Comment: "why don't we use two separate deadlock" do you mean why don't use two synchronized blocks, one after the other? Yes, that is one way to avoid deadlock.

Comment: Example on [Oracle's Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html)

Comment: Is there any reason to use two synchronized blocks ? (one inside another like I used in the first program )

Comment: related: [Simple Deadlock Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1385843/85421) ?

Comment: The essential condition for deadlock is at least two resources, each with a lock, and at least two threads or processes that acquire these locks in different orders. Then you can have thread/process A holding lock and X trying to acquire lock Y, while thread/process B holds lock B and is trying to acquire lock A. This is the simple case: the general case is a chain of N >= 2 threads/processes, all waiting for each other's locks. Two successive `synchronized` blocks does not fall under this description in any way.

Comment: ... and in your example, if you sequentialized the locks you would avoid the deadlock, but you would lose thread-safety. The correct solution is for everybody to acquire the locks in the same order.

Comment: Re, "why don't we use two separate synchronized block?" Because that would defeat the purpose. The main purpose of `synchronized` is to prevent any thread from seeing data in an inconsistent state when some other thread is in the middle of changing it. The `transfer()` example is supposed to show how other threads can see the database before a transaction, or after a transaction, but never in the middle of a transaction. But the gap between the two `synchronized` blocks, no matter how small, affords other threads an opportunity to see it the data when the transaction is only halfway done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a bank with thousands of bank accounts of type `Account`. Now let's look at why this code causes a deadlock:

```
public void transfer(Account a,Account b,int amount)
    {
        synchronized(a)
        {
            a.withdraw(amount);
            System.out.print(amount+" is withdrawn from account a\n");

            try{Thread.sleep(500);}
            catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

            synchronized(b)
            {
                b.deposit(amount);
                System.out.print(amount+" is deposited into account b\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Let there be a thread `tA` and thread `tB`. If thread `tA` runs the following code
`transfer(accountA, AccountB)` while thread `tB` runs `transfer(accountB, accountA)` simultaneously, there could be a chance of deadlock, because if we look at the following order:

> 1. tA: `synchronized(accountA)`
> 2. tB: `synchronized(accountB)`
> 3. tA: tries to lock object `AccountB`, but lock is held by tB => **deadlock**

we see that there is a cyclic dependency between the two, not allowing one of the threads to progress any further.

If we look at your updated code:

```
public void transfer(Account a,Account b,int amount)
    {
        synchronized(a)
        {
            a.withdraw(amount);
            System.out.print(amount+" is withdrawn from account a\n");

            try{Thread.sleep(500);}
            catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        }
        synchronized(b)
        {
            b.deposit(amount);
            System.out.print(amount+" is deposited into account b\n");
        }
    }
```

we must take the following assumptions:

- Account a has unlimited funds, as it could be that a.balance <
  amount, which means a.balance < 0, which breaks our invariant of
  always having a balance>=0.

  - We allow inconsistencies, e.g. if we want to sum up all the current cash, we will sum up less than the actual amount, because your current code allows us to do so.

If we try to fix the code, we would have to make sure that a.balance >= amount before we update our balance. Now let's look at the following scenario:

> 1. Account `a` has `balance < amount`
> 2. We must wait until `a.balance >= amount` to withdraw money from Account `a`
> 3. As we are keeping the lock of Account `a` in this thread, no other thread can ever update `a.balance` => We suffer from **starvation**

To fix these problems, you would either have to use a monitor or condition that checks whether a.balance>=amount to progress and to put the thread in a blocked state, such that the thread can progress or update your code such that the locks are always acquired in the same order.

**Solution #1**: Unique order of acquiring object's locks

If we use an unique order for acquiring locks of the objects, we can ensure that no deadlock can occur as we are acquiring the locks in a specified order, not allowing any cyclic dependencies otherwise known as deadlock.

```
public void transfer(Account a,Account b,int amount)
    {
       //define a specific order, in which locks are acquired
       //the id's of all accounts are unique!
       if(a.id<b.id){
          synchronized(a){
            synchronized(b){
               //do operations here
            }
          }
       }else{
          synchronized(b){
            synchronized(a){
               //do operations here
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

**Solution #2**: Use a producer-consumer pattern to check `a.balance>=amount`.

```
public void transfer(Account a,Account b,int amount)
{
    while(true){
      synchronized(a){
          if(a.balance>=amount){
              //do operations here
          }
      }

        try{Thread.sleep(500);} //Use this as a backoff, as otherwise you'd likely get high congestion
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
    synchronized(b)
    {
       //do operations here
    }
}
```